# Get [String] from NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys

Tags: string, swift, dictionary, nsobject

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys` returns `[NSObject]` but I need (and would expect) `[String]`. Is it just some coffee I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually returns a `LazyBidirectionalCollection<MapCollectionView<Dictionary<Key, Value>, Key>>`. You can add `.array` to get an array instance back, then use `map` to cast the values to `String`:

```
let keys = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.array.map { $0 as String }
println(keys)
// [NSLanguages, NSInterfaceStyle, AppleLanguages]
```

Comment: Obviously both solutions work, but I prefer this as it returns the [String] directly. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

`dictionaryRepresentation()` returns `NSDictionary` that does not support generic types. You can convert to Swift dictionary:

```
let dictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation() as [String : AnyObject]
let keys = dictionary.keys
```